# Vector potential identity

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, potential

This is only a quick question and a reference to useful material would suffice. I have been given the identity for the vector potential

$$
{\bf{A}}=\frac{1}{2}{\bf{B}} \times {\bf{r}}
$$

This identity does not require proof for me to progress in my reading however I can't see how it is derived. How do I prove this identity?

Comment: FWIW, that identity only works if $\vec B$ is constant (independent of $\vec r$).

Comment: Ok thanks my topic does involve a constant $\overrightarrow{B}$ field so that makes sense

Comment: Did you use the [vector triple product identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product#Vector_triple_product)?

Answer (score 4):

If $\bf B$ is constant, 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\nabla \times \left(\frac{1}{2} {\bf B} \times {\bf r}\right) &=& \frac{1}{2} \left[\left({\bf r} \bullet \nabla \right){\bf B}-\left({\bf B} \bullet \nabla\right) {\bf r} + {\bf B} \left(\nabla \bullet {\bf r}\right) - {\bf r} \left(\nabla \bullet {\bf B}\right)\right] \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} \left(0-{\bf B} + 3{\bf B} -0\right) \\
&=& {\bf B}
\end{eqnarray}
$$